# Get rating values in structured schema

Tags: schema.org

I am trying to implement structured schema for my website. But I am not able to understand how to get rating value, review count.
We are not asking our website visitors to submit a review.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This question has a very broad scope. Can you further add more details and specify what exactly do you want? How is your current structured schema?

Comment: <script type="application/ld+json">
       "reviewRating": 
   {
    "@type": "Rating",
    "ratingValue": "4",
    "bestRating": "5"
   },
</script>
I wanted to add rating value here

Comment: It's still not clear. Is there a field in your website which tracks down the rating value and review count?

Comment: No, we are not maintaining any review/rating count. So how to get that ratingValue in schema

Comment: If your current table schema doesn't track review/rating count, you need to create a new table containing the review/rating count column and another column that references the primary key of your existing table. Essentially, a `one-to-many` or `one-to-one`  relationship. And, if you are not tracking the review/rating count, you need to add some mechanism to track these values in your website.

Comment: thanks for your reply..But I have seen many websites which doesn't accept review from customer but they are showing rating in their schema.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement structured schema in HTML website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58950083/implement-structured-schema-in-html-website)

Comment: https://reviewsonmywebsite.com/blog/star-ratings-google-search-results