# Implement structured schema in HTML website

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am implementing structured data (schema.org) for my website.

I am stuck at putting in `ratingValue` and `reviewCount`, everything else I am able to put in dynamically.

```
"review": [
    {
        "@type": "Review",
        "reviewRating":{
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": "4",
            "bestRating": "5"
        },
        "author":{
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "xyz"
        }
    }
],
"aggregateRating": 
{
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "3.7",
    "reviewCount": "15"
}
```

Where I can put `reviewCount` and `ratingValue`?
We are not asking our customers to give any reviews/ratings

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example. aggregateRating should not be inside the review property, but directly inside the item being reviewed. Your review property should contain an array of review items. e.g. [{...},{...},{...}]

Comment: Yes, But my problem is getting rating value as we are not maintaining any review system. Also I have seen many websites which don't have review system but they are showing rating value in schema.

Comment: How do users add a rating?

Comment: Users do not provide any rating. So in this case how we can get rating values. There are many websites which don't have review system but in schema they are showing rating.is there any third party apis avail or from where and how will I get this review count

Comment: Those ratings about your thing have to be submitted by users from somewhere?

Comment: Please add more semantic + more specific Q title (your issue related to "ratingValue and reviewCount" - your Q title is very very general). On Google Review snippet "reviewRating" is a mandatory field (The snippet show stars - no way (For now) to add stars without rating - this is also make sense). https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case using `AggregateRating` doesn't make sense, since there's only a single review by the (assumed) website author. "Aggregate" basically means "the summary of a collection", so to use `AggregateRating` you're stating there are or could be multiple reviews - not just a single one.

Assuming this is a `Product`, I would instead use this markup:

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Some Product",
    "description": "This is some product",
    "review": {
        "@type": "Review",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "xyz"
        },
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "ratingValue": "4",
            "worstRating": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

`AggregateRating` in the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) is recommended, but not required.

If for some reason you have to use `AggregateRating` in this project, then you could hardcode the `reviewCount` as `1` and set the `ratingValue` to the value you're already pulling into `reviewRating`. Again though, that defeats the purpose of `AggregateRating`.